# python bokeh saving issue and label disappear, and display problem

Tags: python, svg, save, bokeh

As I am aiming to plot the data into the plot, I encounter 2 problems.

(1) For the Bokeh function, while I am plotting 4 pictures in a row and adding the save as the SVG. Then the browser is shown as figure1. Moreover, as I comment out the code below, it work definitely right as I thought. It's weird.

```py
p1.output_backend = "svg"
export_svgs(p1, filename="./number_like_comment/fig/{}.svg".format(action_str))
```

[image]
[image]

(2) For the second question, after I save those files, I realized that the "Label" I put in the plot also disappear. (as figure3).

[image]

Thanks so much for reading through. This question bother me quite a long time.

Comment: In both scenarios, do you see any errors in the JavaScript console? Are there any Python errors?

Comment: On the Bokeh Console, there is no error. But on the js console, it looks like this. https://imgur.com/a/5qgQRcL

Comment: Ah, I see that you have already opened an issue on GitHub. Please also provide all the errors there. Preferably not only the screenshot but also the full text of a single error expanded using the triangle on the left.

Comment: Thanks!! I'll do it right away

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/xQDnMig

Comment: Does the data "Number of Interaction" start at 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that the data (on the x-axis) starts at 0, and on a logaxis for some reason the svg renderer doesn't like that and refuses to draw the entire line. The canvas renderer (used for the interactive plots) only refuses to draw the line-segment going from or to 0.

If you want to keep the logarithmic axis, you can either remove the 0 values or replace them by something which can be displayed in a logarithmic scale (e.g. 0.1) and then fixate the x-axis.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, Just wake up. I remove the 0 value in both the x and y-axis. it works!! Huge thanks for the reach out.

Currently, there is still a problem in showing the Label while saving SVG. I've e search through the Issue pages, it seems to be a problem of not detecting the DOM in the HTML. I'd like to ask whether it is solved or having another way around. (The problem is noted in problem 2 above) Huge Thanks for the help.